# Who should be our moderators?

Tags: discussion

From the [Moderator Blog article](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

> About a week into the public beta, we will seek out members who are
>   deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:
>
> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active,
>     consistent participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow
>     community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of
>     Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).
>
> Bonus points for:
>
> - Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e.
>     interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
> - Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about
>     the site.
> - Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote
>     their community.
>
> Candidates will be contacted and three of them will be selected to act
>   as provisional Moderators until the community holds formal elections
>   after the Beta period. Besides the normal abilities of a Moderator,
>   they will:
>
> - Have access to a special chat room where we will collectively work
>     through the challenges of moderation and community self-policing.
> - Organize the process of selecting the site’s attributes (domain
>     names, design issues, the FAQ, etc.).
> - Rally community support and drive the mission of getting publicity
>     for the site.
>
> Essentially, they will have the ear of the Stack Exchange team for
>   anything we can do to help their sites succeed! Make Sure Your
>   Community is Well Represented
>
> If your meta site does not have a post to nominate Moderators, start
>   one now! Pro Tem appointments will begin about two weeks after the
>   site is created. The more guidance we receive, the more informed our
>   choice.
>
> This is the basic structure of a Moderator nomination thread:
>
> - The question should be community wiki.
> - Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the
>     user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
> - The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer,
>     adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write
>     something about themselves.
> - Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not
>     had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is
>     simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.”
>     Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation,
>     participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the
>     site, etc.

Comment: We have to make this question a wiki

Comment: I would, but recent changes have prohibited CW for questions (Answers are still okay...) I could flag it for moderator attention...

Comment: What does CW stand for?

Comment: @Phonon: CW= Community Wiki

Comment: Sorry, long day = )

Comment: I think it's just about time to revive this post. Any candidates?

Answer (score 8):

[Yoda](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/77/yoda) certainly sticks out. ([Meta](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77/yoda)) Yoda has been heavily involved in both meta and the main site, and is currently the highest ranked user. Yoda has already been taking a moderator-like role, as much as one can do without the full mod powers.

Comment: I second that; yoda seems to be the obvious choice.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto & Jason: Thank you for the kind words, I accept the nomination. I'm also a moderator on [gardening.se] and you're welcome to vet my [activity there](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/109/yoda?tab=activity#page_1-filter_all) (mostly janitorial) or on the corresponding [meta](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/users/109/yoda) :)

Answer (score 6):

I nominate [Phonon](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/6/phonon). Phonon has been active on the site, especially in seeding it with good questions (which is very critical and we came --><-- this close to shutting down). He's a prolific voter and has also been active on [meta](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6/phonon), raising important issues and providing good suggestions.

Comment: I'm somewhat hesitant in accepting the nomination because I've never moderated anything on StackExchange. Is there a document with guidelines and commitment requirements? I certainly don't mind though = )

Comment: @phonon There is a dedicated chatroom for moderators across the network where you can discuss issues, bounce off ideas and in general, consult for advice. Most issues (re: spam/troublesome users/quality/janitorial work/etc) are common across the sites and there's always be someone in there who can help. As with everything, you pick up things and learn along the way :) You can read [this blogpost](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) which pretty much sums up the duties and the moderation policy

Comment: Great, I'd be glad to do it then.

Answer (score 5):

I'll add another name to the pool: [datageist](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/35/datageist). He is calm, level headed (from what I could tell from comments here and elsewhere on the network), has good knowledge of the field and has a fair [meta](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/users/35/datageist) participation, given the general low activity on the site.

Answer (score 4):

I nominate [Peter K](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/users/80/peter-k). He was initially responsible for the idea, followed through all the way and is now active on the site. If anyone, he should definitely be among the moderators.